# How to get emitted data from signal to a defined slot in python

Tags: python, signals, signals-slots

I am using [enter link description here][1] link to create the signal and emit the data to defined slot, here is my sample code below,

library link https://pypi.org/project/signalslot/0.0.2/

```
main.py
---------------
import network 

def __init__(self):
    networkOb = network()
    self.network = self.networkObj.conf_pre_load.connect(self.recvdata)

def recvdata(self, data):
        print("****** main  slot")
        print(data)
        print("==============")

*******************************************

netowrk.py
-----------
import signalslot

def __init__():
  self.conf_pre_load = signalslot.Signal(args="some_data")
  self.readUdpdata()

def readUdpdata():
    while True:
            try:
                data, addr = self.socket_rcv.recvfrom(size)
                self._data = "hello"
                self.conf_pre_load.emit("self._data")
                
            except Exception as e:
                
                print(e)
```

```
i am getting this error
--------------------------
    raise exceptions.IncompatibleSlotSignature()
signalslot.exceptions.IncompatibleSlotSignature
```

when network class emits the data, i am trying to receive the data from slot inside main class, have been struggling since 1 day, help would be more appreciated

Comment: Please provide complete code. I am not able to run this code like this. These are all just methods, and no call to any method.

Comment: please check library you will get an idea, what i am trying to do, `self.conf_pre_load` is declared in network, and using same to connect `signal() in main ` using `signalslot` library, once connected trying to emit the data from network inside `while loop` ignore ip, port, trying to emit hard coded data, in emit, the data has to be captured from `slot` which is declared by the signal instance